# Issue with passing parameter using jquery/signalr

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am writing a simple Comment section using MVC and SignalR. First, the Comment View subscribes to the hub (using a "UserParticipationId" that will be used to create a group name). Then, once someone leaves a comment, the view will be sending the comment to the hub (called chathub) and the chathub will broadcast the message to all Views using the groupname.

So the two methods of my hub are:

```
    public void subscribetogroup(int userparticipationid)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userparticipationid.ToString());
    }

    public void broadcastnewcomment(string comment, string commenterid, int userparticipationid)
    {
        Comment cmt = new Comment
        {
            CommenterId = commenterid,
            CommentDate = DateTime.Now,
            UserParticipationId = userparticipationid,
            CommentText = comment
        };

        //_commentRepository.AddCommentToUserParticipation(cmt);

        Clients.Group(userparticipationid.ToString()).displaynewcomment(comment);
    }
```

The script code in my view is:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var hub = $.connection.chathub;

            hub.client.displaynewcomment = function (comment) {
                alert(comment);
            };

            //hub.client.displaynewcomment = function (comment) {
            //    Html.RenderPartial("_CommentCardPartial", comment);
            //};

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                hub.server.subscribetogroup(@Model.UserParticipationId);

                $('#CommentButton').click(function () {
                    //var enteredcomment = $('#CommentText').val();
                    @*hub.server.broadcastnewcomment(enteredcomment, @Model.CommenterId, @Model.UserParticipationId);*@
                    hub.server.broadcastnewcomment("Hello", "hala", 2);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

So my question is twofold:

1. If I call my hub using constants, the method call works (verified using VS debugger):

   hub.server.broadcastnewcomment("Hello", "hi", 2);

However, if I use variables from my Model, the method never gets called:

```
hub.server.broadcastnewcomment(@Model.Comment, @Model.CommenterId, @Model.UserParticipationId);
```

To make it even more confusing (to me anyway), the following line always works:

```
hub.server.subscribetogroup(@Model.UserParticipationId);
```

2. How do I mix Model variables (e.g. @Model.CommenterId) and the value that I read from a textarea using jquery. I have commented out what I have in my view, but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I have been running some more tests and for some reason, the issue with broadcastnewcomment seem to appear when I try to send variables of type string. I just tried replacing the method parameters to a bunch of int variable, and the call worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single codes for string values in parameters of js function. String type values of @Model must be wrapped inside single codes like this:

```
hub.server.broadcastnewcomment('@Model.Comment', '@Model.CommenterId', @Model.UserParticipationId);
```

Comment: Although this may work, I would strongly recommend escaping the quotes... You have a big XSS risk if the comment is ever user editable.